# Height of a child view is exceeding height of CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml

Below are the xml code of my `MainActivity`, I think it's pretty standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However, I got this result in preview:

[image]

Just for the sake of testing, I created an xml which contains text from A to N:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="AAA"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="BBB"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="CCC"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="DDD"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="EEE"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FFF"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="GGG"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="HHH"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="III"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="JJJ"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="KKK"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="LLL"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="MMM"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="NNN"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here's the result on my Nexus 6, scrolled to the very bottom:

[image]

As you can see, the height of `ViewPager` is exceeding its parent layout causing some elements below clipped, and I wonder why? I'm using API level 23, it might be the root cause but I can't lower it down because I'm using a library that highly depends on API 23.

Can someone clarify is this a bug? I can use `paddingBottom` or `layout_MarginBottom` as a quick solution but I don't think it's elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by using `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`, not regular `ScrollView`.

Comment: Yeah.! That's the better choice !

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a bug. Its the function of "app:layout_behavior" attribute in your view pager. Don't worry its pretty normal thing and it works perfectly fine when you run it on any Android device.

Comment: I forgot to attach a screenshot of the app running on an actual device. It's actually affected, some elements below are clipped.

Comment: When you scroll over your content in the viewpager, the toolbar will scroll and hide inside the status bar and your tablayout will take its place. This transition is similar to what takes place in latest version of WhatsApp application. In order for it to function properly, this effect if required.

Comment: See "CoordinatorLayout and the app bar" in the link for more details :- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check the test xml and screenshot, I hope you get the idea and thank you very much for helping.